# How to sum table td value with search option

Tags: javascript, html

I need to calculate the total value of row right now as per code it's calculating total row and sometimes in the result, it's showing 1 extra row you can try to search (a) you will see.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filter").keyup(function(){
        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
  
        $("tbody tr").each(function(){
 
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();
           
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });
        
        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-count").text("NUMBER OF ROW FOUND = "+count);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
<fieldset>
<input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="" placeholder="Search" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<div id="filter-count"></div>
<table>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>250</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>250</td></tr>
    <tr><td>b</td><td>250</td></tr>
    <tr><td>b</td><td>250</td></tr>
    <tr><td>c</td><td>250</td></tr>
    <tr><td>c</td><td>250</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: for `b` and `c` it works fine

Comment: it's probably the `a's` in `Name` and `Amount` that are doing it - try n, m, e, o, u or t - they come back with a count of `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with Name and Amount in the th's - they have an `a` in them, therefore that row is included in the count

You **should have noticed** in your code, that if you search for b or c, then the header row also disappear!!

Try putting the header in a `thead` (in a tr in the thead, by the way)

and the body in a `tbody`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filter").keyup(function(){
        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
        var total = 0;
        $("tbody tr").each(function(){
 
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();
           
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                total += Number($(this).find('td:last-child').text());
                count++;
            }
        });
        
        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-count").text("NUMBER OF ROW FOUND = "+ count + ' Total value= ' + total);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
<fieldset>
<input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="" placeholder="Search" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<div id="filter-count"></div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>250</td></tr>
        <tr><td>a</td><td>250</td></tr>
        <tr><td>b</td><td>250</td></tr>
        <tr><td>b</td><td>250</td></tr>
        <tr><td>c</td><td>250</td></tr>
        <tr><td>c</td><td>250</td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: extra 1 issue is solved Thanks but I need to sum Amount as per search result

Comment: well, you haven't even attempted that in your code -let me see if I can write that for you

Comment: Done - I've now added summing of amount for you

Comment: Awesome Thanks for quick response